# incorrect syntax error near ,debit

Tags: c#, sql

i am facing problem .in this ...the error is   .incorrect syntax near DEBIT

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::databaseform.Properties.Settings.Default.Database2ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            //string sql = "INSERT INTO student(Id,name) values (" + textBox1.Text + ",'" + textBox2.Text + "')";

            //JOURNAL
            string sql = "INSERT INTO journal(user_Id, DATE, MEMO, ACCOUNT DEBIT, ACCOUNT CREDIT, AMOUNT DEBIT, AMOUNT CREDIT) values (" + user_id.Text + "," + date.Text + ",'" + memo.Text + "','" + debit.Text + "','" + credit.Text + "'," + debit_am.Text + "," + credit_am.Text + ")";
            SqlCommand eesql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cn.Open();
            eesql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Add new record  done ||", " Message ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.journalTableAdapter.Fill(this.database2DataSet.journal);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, " ERROR ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: your fields have spaces in the names. you need to bracket them, e.g. `[ACCOUNT CREDIT]` Of course, you don't want WHAT database this is, so its specific quoting requirements may be different. Regardless, you can't have fields whose names have spaces or other invalid characters WITHOUT handling them specially.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to add quotes or brackets around your field names that have spaces
2. You should get in the habit of using parameters

   ```
   //JOURNAL
   string sql = "INSERT INTO journal(user_Id, DATE, MEMO, [ACCOUNT DEBIT], [ACCOUNT CREDIT], [AMOUNT DEBIT], [AMOUNT CREDIT])" + 
                " values " + 
                " (@userid, @date, @memo, @debit, @credit, @debit_am, @credit_am)";
   SqlCommand eesql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
   eesql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", user_id.Text);
   eesql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.Text);
   ..etc.
   ```

The three main reasons for using parameters are:

1. SQL Injection protection
2. eliminate need to add string delimiters
3. eliminate risk of input values having quotes that will produce syntax errors